# Windows authentication for internet access pop ups

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome

Many of my users are on a tightly controlled network where they are required to fill out an additional log in prompt when accessing the internet.  In IE (7/8) this dialog box has the option to save their credentials, in Chrome/FF they can't save their credentials and they have to re-enter them every time.

I would like to understand why IE allows that information to saved and the other browsers do not (my guess is something to do with ActiveX).

Also is there anyway to provide similar functionality in chrome, we are trying to push our users towards chrome for the apps we develop for them but this password entry tends to be a sticking point for many.  (I know they have to remember a password! gasp)

Any insight would be great thanks